# How to make a get request from a web application running at one origin to a message broker which runs at a different origin

Tags: reactjs, axios

I want to make an api get request through axios from my react app which runs in port 3000 to a message broker which runs in port 9000.Due since they are in different origins chrome is not allowing me to do the api call.How can I do this?